# CTE in cursor gives "Connection is busy with results for another command" error while derived table does not

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, derived-table

I ran into an error recently while fetching from a cursor on a query that utilized a CTE.

"[Microsoft][SQL Server native Client 10.0]Connection is bust with results for another command"

The error was occurring on a subsequent cursor that is executed on each iteration of the fetch.

I was able to resolve the error by replacing the CTE with a derived table.

I need to know why the derived table works fine, while the CTE fails, and if I did something wrong in the CTE example.

The original query was relatively complex, involving multiple joins, but basically amounts to the following:

```
WITH cteResults AS (
    SELECT Account.Id AS AccountId
    FROM Accounts AS Account
    WHERE Account.Number = '12345'
    UNION
    SELECT SubAccount.Id
    FROM SubAccounts AS SubAccount
    WHERE SubAccount.Number = '12345')

SELECT
    Invoice.Value AS InvoiceValue,
    CASE
        WHEN Representative.Sequence IS NOT NULL THEN THEN Representative.Name
        ELSE Account.OwnerName
    END AS InvoiceName
FROM cteResults
INNER JOIN Invoices AS Invoice ON
    Invoice.AccountId = cteResults.AccountId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Accounts AS Account ON
    Account.Id = Invoice.AccountId
LEFT OUTER JOIN AccountRepresentatives AS Representative ON
    Representative.Id = Invoices.AccountRepresentativeId
```

The code in question would loop through a cursor using the above statement, and for each iteration of FETCH, it would execute a second cursor:

```
FOREACH InvoicesCursor INTO InvoiceResults.*
    OPEN FormattingRulesCursor
    FETCH FormattingRulesCursor into FormattingRules.*
    // Error appears here
    CLOSE FormattingRulesCursor
END FOREACH
```

Any cursor that is opened from the application during the FOREACH statement fails with the error I mentioned above.

However, if I drop the CTE and use a derived table, I do not receive the error and everything works appropriately.

```
SELECT
    Invoice.Value AS InvoiceValue,
    CASE
        WHEN Representative.Sequence IS NOT NULL THEN THEN Representative.Name
        ELSE Account.OwnerName
    END AS InvoiceName
FROM (SELECT Account.Id AS AccountId
    FROM Accounts AS Account
    WHERE Account.Number = '12345'
    UNION
    SELECT SubAccount.Id
    FROM SubAccounts AS SubAccount
    WHERE SubAccount.Number = '12345') AS cteResults
INNER JOIN Invoices AS Invoice ON
    Invoice.AccountId = cteResults.AccountId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Accounts AS Account ON
    Account.Id = Invoice.AccountId
LEFT OUTER JOIN AccountRepresentatives AS Representative ON
    Representative.Id = Invoices.AccountRepresentativeId
```

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but, what operations are being performed by the cursors? Have you considered a set based approach?

Comment: The query results are consumed by the application to populate a program array for a browse screen.

My example has been overly simplified for brevity.  

In this case the second query actually belongs to another department within my company and is part of a business logic component used to format data elements for display.

I'm sure that this logic would have been better implemented as part of a SP, but unfortunately I don't have any control over that.